# How to use JavaScript/JQuery to download a PDF from a URL, then POST the file to a different site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf

I currently have a URL to a PDF file like this: http://www.example.com/HelloWorld.pdf

What I would like to do is use this URL to download the file and store it momentarily on the browser so that I can POST it to http://www.example2.com/api/Uploads (I don't want to save it on the user's machine)

My goal is to achieve this using JavaScript/JQuery/AJAX. I'm currently reading documentation for [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and also going through this [post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).

Will downloading the PDF into a blob and trying to upload the raw data even work? Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I don't want to save it on the user's machine"_ Then why have the client retireve the file in the first place? Just send the url to the server, and have the server download it

Answer (score 0):

You would face with security issues in your browser. For example: "[Cross origin request](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20cross%20origin)". You can't just run a script that would download arbitrary files without jumping hell a lot of hoops and even then, the feasibility would be questionable.